# Access Query Criteria return weekend range if monday, else return yesterday

Tags: ms-access, criteria, weekday

Using Access 2007

This is my first question and i apologize in advance if anything is asked "the wrong way".

I have a huge database regarding invoices at work. 
We want to have a counter showing "How many invoices did we recieve yesterday, if it's monday, how many did we recieve on friday, saturday and sunday?"

The counter itself is no issue, but the query criteria to make it get multiple days is really annoying me (lack of knowledge)

It seems to be subtracting 3 days regardless of what day it is.

Why is the following not working in query criteria? (Not returning friday, saturday and sunday values when monday and yesterdays results if NOT monday?)

```
IIf(Weekday(Date()=2);<=Date()-3;Date()-1)
```

*Edit: I'm using a danish version of Access 2007, which is why there's ; instead of ,*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the result of `IIf()` as full criteria expression, but you can use it as criteria parameter. Use a WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE (DateDiff("d",[InvoiceDate],Date()) <= IIf(Weekday(Date())=2,3,1)) 
  AND (DateDiff("d",[InvoiceDate],Date()) >= 1)
```

In the query design editor both criteria will be combined into one column (German Access here).

[image: Query editor (German)]

Omit `AND (DateDiff("d",[InvoiceDate],Date()) >= 1` if you want to include invoices from today.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and edit, Andre!
I think i am not following somewhere here. 
My access messed up and wanted me to edit , to ; and same with the "2,3,1". Also changed [InvoiceDate] to [ModtagelsesDato] as that's the field name for RecievedDate :) 

When i try to run it, is comes back with "There's a non-defined function "WHERE" in the expression". 

You must be facepalming at the moment, but where do i input "WHERE.........." for it to work. Sorry for my inexperience and thanks for your patience

Comment: Working like a charm! Thanks for your patience!